# Php Mailer is not working with batch file emailing?

Tags: php, wampserver

While I am trying to execute *php mailer* from a batch file shows this error,

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find
the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you
configured PHP? (24) <br />SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host
```

Comment: In windows, make sure you do have ssl enabled. Make sure the `openssl` extension is loaded.

Comment: In My php ini file extemtion=PHP_openssl.dill is loaded.

Comment: Does ssl enable for your website?